# Improve speed of query with st_dump(multipolygon)

Tags: postgis, postgresql, performance

My query has lost a lot of performance only when I add st_dump do split multipolygon. When I add st_dump, the query spent 4 minutes against without it has run in 38s.

What can I do to improve performance of my query? What can I do to improve the speed of st_dump (I can't remove it from query. I need to split multipolygons)?

```
SELECT (select unnest(array_agg(m2.object_id)) as id_array2 order by id_array2 limit 1) AS id, t1.class_name, t1.view_date, t1.geom
FROM (
    SELECT t.class_name, t.view_date, t.geom
    FROM (
        SELECT m.class_name, ts.view_date,
            (st_dump(st_buffer(st_union(m.spatial_data), 0, 'join=mitre'))).geom AS geom
        FROM monitoramento m 
        INNER JOIN terraamazon.ta_scene ts ON m.scene_id = ts.id
        WHERE m.class_name <> 'Erro_T0'
        GROUP BY m.class_name, ts.view_date
    ) t
) t1
JOIN monitoramento m2 ON ST_Intersects(st_pointonsurface(m2.spatial_data), t1.geom)
GROUP BY t1.class_name, t1.view_date, t1.geom;

"GroupAggregate  (cost=17365476452.11..17365757185.42 rows=320000 width=56)"
"  Group Key: m.class_name, ts.view_date, ((st_dump(_st_buffer(st_union(m.spatial_data), '0'::double precision, 'join=mitre'::cstring))).geom)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=17365476452.11..17365530038.77 rows=21434665 width=56)"
"        Sort Key: m.class_name, ts.view_date, ((st_dump(_st_buffer(st_union(m.spatial_data), '0'::double precision, 'join=mitre'::cstring))).geom)"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2741.01..17362133782.20 rows=21434665 width=56)"
"              Join Filter: ((st_pointonsurface(m2.spatial_data) && ((st_dump(_st_buffer(st_union(m.spatial_data), '0'::double precision, 'join=mitre'::cstring))).geom)) AND _st_intersects(st_pointonsurface(m2.spatial_data), ((st_dump(_st_buffer(st_union(m.spatial_data), '0'::double precision, 'join=mitre'::cstring))).geom)))"
"              ->  HashAggregate  (cost=2741.01..19573.01 rows=3200000 width=52)"
"                    Group Key: m.class_name, ts.view_date"
"                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=110.44..2592.29 rows=19830 width=709)"
"                          Hash Cond: (m.scene_id = ts.id)"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on monitoramento m  (cost=0.00..2209.19 rows=19830 width=709)"
"                                Filter: ((class_name)::text <> 'Erro_T0'::text)"
"                          ->  Hash  (cost=65.75..65.75 rows=3575 width=8)"
"                                ->  Seq Scan on ta_scene ts  (cost=0.00..65.75 rows=3575 width=8)"
"              ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..2259.42 rows=20095 width=693)"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on monitoramento m2  (cost=0.00..2158.95 rows=20095 width=693)"
"  SubPlan 1"
"    ->  Limit  (cost=0.02..0.03 rows=1 width=4)"
"          ->  Sort  (cost=0.02..0.52 rows=100 width=4)"
"                Sort Key: (unnest(array_agg(m2.object_id)))"
"                ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=4)"
```

Comment: please include the `explain` output of your query

Comment: Thank for your help. I add what you ask me.